# How to Read All the Data available in Excell Column using it's column name and storing them in Hashset(Excluding The Column Name)

Tags: java, excel

I have a working code, But the problem is it's putting even the column name in to my HashSet. Please let me know if there is any error in this code.

```
EXAMPLE EXCELL:
|PhoneNumber | name|
|1234567890  | xyz |
|2131242342  | zyx |
|2332233222  | yxa |
|7625423423  | abc |

public HashSet<String> getAllColumnValue(String columnName){
    HashSet<String> rowList = new HashSet<String>();
    int columnIndex = 0;
    boolean flage = false;
    String value=null;
    for (Row row : spreadsheet) {
        if(!flage){
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                value = cell.getStringCellValue().trim();
                if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(columnName)) {
                    columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
                    flage = true;
                }
            }
        }           
        if (flage && !columnName.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            Cell cell1 = row.getCell(columnIndex);
            if(cell1!=null){
               if(cell1.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC){
                   if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell1)) {
                     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy");
                     Date date = cell1.getDateCellValue();
                     rowList.add(df.format(date));
            } else {
                            cell1.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                                rowList.add(cell1.toString());  
                        }
                    } else {
                        cell1.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                        rowList.add(cell1.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    return rowList;
}
```

Lets say, above is my excell which has Phone Number and name as Columns and specic set of values on each column. Now I'm trying to read the data in Phone Number column and So I'm calling `getAllColumnValue(PhoneNumber)`. My expectation is to return a HashSet

`[1234567890, 2131242342, 2332233222, 7625423423]`

but when I get the result it will be

`[1234567890, 2131242342, 2332233222, 7625423423, PhoneNumber]`

Here I'm calling getAllColumnValue method from an other class file and this method should return me all the values in specific column based on the column I specify while calling the method. Unfortunately it even shows the column name on the Hashset when I print the Returned list.